# Unexpected behaviour when using TTY-Prompt

Tags: ruby

```
require 'tty-prompt'
def landing_page
    prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
    choices = ["Create", "Update", "Delete", "Quit"]
    answer = prompt.multi_select("Select", choices)
    case answer
        when choices[0]
            puts "works"
        else
            puts "doesn't work"
            sleep(1)
            self.landing_page
        end
    end


landing_page
```

It's my first time trying to make a terminal app using TTY-Prompt. I'm trying to test the ^above piece of code and expect it to return "works" when the user selects "Create" from the list but it doesn't. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Answer is replace `multi_select` with `select`. Thanks to Stefan for clearing that up.

Comment: _"Am I missing something?"_ – `multi_select` returns an _array_ of selected values, not a single value. You could check via `answer.include?(choices[0])` whether `"Create"` is one of them.

Comment: @Stefan Oh man, I feel dumb now. Totally missed it. Thank you!